# Build not available on iTunes Connect for internal testing through CircleCI fastlane deployment

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, testflight, fastlane

I am currently trying to set up iOS deployment for a React-Native app, using Fastlane through CircleCI, and I am having an issue where I get to `pilot` in my fastlane script, I upload the build to iTunes Connect, but the build disappears from being used for TestFlight Internal Testers. If I archive locally and upload the build to iTunes Connect, it will be available for testing.

My `Fastfile`, using version `2.51.0`

```ruby
platform :ios do
  lane :deploy_staging do
    match(
      type: "adhoc",
      force: true
    )

    increment_build_number(
      xcodeproj: './ios/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    )

    gym(
      export_method: "ad-hoc",
      scheme: "MyApp Staging",
      project: "./ios/MyApp.xcodeproj"
    )
    pilot(
      skip_submission: false,
      distribute_external: false,
    )

    clean_build_artifacts
    git_add(
      path: '.'
    )
    git_commit(
      path: '.',
      message: "Deployed new staging version #{lane_context[SharedValues::BUILD_NUMBER]} [skip ci]",
    )
    push_to_git_remote(
      local_branch: ENV["CIRCLE_BRANCH"],
      remote_branch: ENV["CIRCLE_BRANCH"]
    )
  end
end
```

My `circle.yml`

```ruby
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: '$PATH:$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64/bin'
  xcode:
    version: 8.3.3

dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - $HOME/node
  pre:
    - "ls \"$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64\" || mkdir \"$HOME/node\""
    - "ls \"$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64\" || curl -L \"https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.1.3/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz\" -o \"$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz\""
    - "ls \"$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64\" || tar -xzf \"$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz\" -C \"$HOME/node/\""
    - "rm -f \"$HOME/node/node-v8.1.3-darwin-x64.tar.gz\""
  override:
    - npm install -g react-native-cli
    - npm install

test:
  override:
    - npm test
  post:
    - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/
    - find . -type f -regex ".*/test_out/.*xml" -exec cp {} $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/ \;

deployment:
  pre:
    - gem install fastlane
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - npm run build:ios
      - fastlane deploy_staging
```

Output from the CircleCI test

[image: CircleCI results]

Build completed processing on iTunes Connect

[image: iTunes Connect]

Build not available (invisible) on TestFlight tab

[image: TestFlight]

I tried debugging this by archiving locally with the same certificates and profiles, but it uploads successfully and I am able to distribute to internal testers on TestFlight.

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution that helped resolve this issue.

Two parts seem to help fix it

1. Changing profile used from `adhoc` to `appstore`

   a.  I had to generate the appstore provisioning profile through match:

   ```
     fastlane match appstore -a com.myapp.app.staging
   ```
2. Adding `include_symbols` and `include_bitcode` to my `gym` build parameters.

Processing took longer than normal, but after processing, it returns to the build list where `pilot` recognizes it and it posts to TestFlight.

My new Fastfile:

```
  lane :deploy_staging do    
    match(
      type: "appstore"
    )

    increment_build_number(
      xcodeproj: './ios/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    )

    gym(
      include_symbols: true,
      include_bitcode: true,
      export_method: "app-store",
      scheme: "MyApp Staging",
      project: "./ios/MyApp.xcodeproj"
    ) # Build your app - more options available

    pilot

    clean_build_artifacts
    git_add(
      path: '.'
    )
    git_commit(
      path: '.',
      message: "Deployed new staging version #{lane_context[SharedValues::BUILD_NUMBER]} [skip ci]",
    )
    push_to_git_remote(
      local_branch: ENV["CIRCLE_BRANCH"],
      remote_branch: ENV["CIRCLE_BRANCH"]
    )

  end
```